# Chars after dot are removed while executing dynamic sql

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a SQL statement like below:-

```
DECLARE @DbName NVARCHAR(200)='model54.18',@SQL NVARCHAR(MAX)

SET @SQL='
USE '+@DbName+'
EXEC (@SQL)
```

When I am trying to execute this statement it is removing '.18' from my DbName and throwing error that database model54 doesn't exists.

Any idea how to resolve this??

Answer (score 3):

You need to use `Quotename` to escape `dot` in database name

```
DECLARE @DbName NVARCHAR(200)='model54.18',@SQL NVARCHAR(MAX)

SET @SQL='USE '+quotename(@DbName)
print @sql
EXEC (@SQL)
```

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables - Nope am the first one to answer

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables No, he had his answer in first with `QUOTENAME`

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables - Blindly commenting without knowing the fact

Comment: @NoDisplayName - no need to be a jerk about it, I was merely commenting and guessing at the DV.  Sorry I didn't take a screenshot of your answer before commenting :P

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables - Fine but stop assuming things like this.

Answer (score 3):

Try it like this:

```
DECLARE @DbName NVARCHAR(200)='model54.18',@SQL NVARCHAR(MAX)

SET @SQL='
USE ['+@DbName+']'
EXEC (@SQL)
```

Or like this:

```
DECLARE @DbName NVARCHAR(200)='model54.18',@SQL NVARCHAR(MAX)

SET @SQL='
USE '+QUOTENAME(@DbName)
EXEC (@SQL)
```

Comment: Unbalanced parentheses.  But other than that, correct.

Comment: @DouglasBarbin  <scratches head>  Where?  I'm not seeing it..?

Comment: At the end of the `USE` line.  The final concatentation never closes the parentheses.  The error was present in the OP so you probably just copied it from there.